# Perl version changes?

Tags: perl, cgi

I wrote some perl cgis 20 years ago. They worked perfectly ... until my hosting company has updated my machine last week. A Perl cgi blocks. It seems it is because the following sequence :

```
require "quiest.htm";
require "quiest.pay";
require "quiest.ent";
```

is not understood as meaning "use these three scripts in the same directory" anymore.

Which would be the correct entry?

I tried quite everything else in terms of reloads, site reorganizing, etc. (the script is called by an HTML page requesting a user entry) everything resulted in a "site.tld\nameof.cgi?string=xxxxx 404)

Comment: It never meant "use these three scripts in the **same** directory". It did mean "use these three scripts in the **current** directory [or...]"

Answer (score 4):

They [removed the current directory](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.26.0/perldelta#Removal-of-the-current-directory-(%22.%22)-from-@INC) (`.`) from `@INC` in Perl 5.26.

The link above includes some solutions:

- You can set the `PERL_USE_UNSAFE_INC` environment variable to `1`.
- Manually add your secure path to `@INC`:

```
BEGIN {
    my $dir = "/some/trusted/directory";
    chdir $dir or die "Can't chdir to $dir: $!\n";
    # safe now
    push @INC, '.';
}
```

Also, as @ikegami reminded me in the comments, [FindBin](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin) exists:

```
use FindBin;
use lib $FindBin::Bin;
```

Comment: These are all wrong. They don't want the current directory added to `@INC`; they want the script's dir.

Comment: @ikegami - I thought that was kind of a strange way of going about it, myself, but suspected there might be _some reason_ for it.  `push @INC, '/some/trusted/directory';` seems a lot more obvious.

Comment: Or using FindBin to find the script's dir